# Count of Intersection Returns Unexpected Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I have to tables, say A and B and a common column X which **isn't nullable**.

Query 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A
WHERE A.X in                       
(SELECT distinct(B.X) FROM B)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM B
WHERE B.X in
(SELECT distinct(X) FROM A)
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A, B
WHERE A.X=B.X
```

Query 1 results 5990. Query 2 and 3 results 6222. Removing `distinct` or checking distinct count on top doesn't change the results. Can someone explain why the results aren't the same for all queries as they all return intersection count?

Comment: They aren't the same logically: Your results imply that there are more non-distinct values in A.X :  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67623/7

Comment: moving the distinct to the count(Distinct *) may work if they are infact all fields duplicated. count(distinct X) would result in the same count across tables as you would be eliminating duplicates.

Comment: distinct(*) didn't work, because the whole row wasn't the same. it's distinct(X) which is worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume A has values 
A
B
C

Assume B has values
A
B
C
D
E
C

in this case A would have a count of 3 (QRY1)
while B would have a count of 4 since c is repeated (QRY2)
when you use a join C will match will all values of C has more duplicates than A.  A may have duplicates but fewer of them. 4 again (QRY3)

Comment: I had to select count(distinct X).